# Angular filter does not trigger in IE and Firefox when input type is date

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

It appears that whenever you specify your input type to be date, the filter function in angular does not get triggered. I have created a fiddle to demonstrate this issue - http://jsfiddle.net/5mo5fgf4/1/

```
<input ng-model="dateTypeSpecified" type="date"/>
<input ng-model="noType"/>

angular.module('demo', [])
    .filter("formatDateValues", function($filter) {
        return function (val) {
            return val+" success"
        };
    });

angular.bootstrap(document, ['demo']);
```

Both inputs work on Chrome but the input with the date type does not seem to work on Firefox and IE.

Any solution to address this if you still want to keep the input type as date?

Comment: What do you mean by *"it doesn't work"*? What's the result on Firefox and IE?

Comment: In the JS fiddle example, the binding doesn't update and the filter does not get triggered either when you add a value to the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this using webshims. I added the following line of extra code -

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/webshim/1.14.5/polyfiller.js"></script>
<script>
    webshims.setOptions('forms-ext', {types: 'date'});
    webshims.polyfill('forms forms-ext');
</script>
```

Updated Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5mo5fgf4/3/